# That may affect the operation of the function imagerotate ()?

Tags: php, apache, gd

There was a problem:

```
for($i = 2; $i <= 6; $i++)
{
  if( $i == 4 ) continue;
  $st_ang = $this->_aHouse[$i];
  $st_ang = $st_ang - $this->_Asc - 180 - 30;
  $image_2 = imagecreatefrompng('./image/blue_line.png');
  $image_2 = imagerotate($image_2, $st_ang, -1, 0);
  imagesetbrush($image_1, $image_2);
  imageline($image_1, imagesx($image_1) / 2, imagesy($image_1) / 2, imagesx($image_1) / 2, imagesy($image_1) / 2, IMG_COLOR_BRUSHED);
  imagedestroy($image_2);
}
```

This code does not want to work within the framework.

Created a project on a separate host - everything works wonderfully.

P.S .: machine is the same.

Problems connected with the third argument is the function `imagerortate();`. I go pass `-1` for the transparency of the background, if you pass `0`, for example, everything will be fine, but the result did not meet my expectations.

Comment: So what are you actually doing with the image after you've rotated it?

Comment: @MarkBaker superimposed over the $image_1

Comment: What I mean is that I don't see any logic for saving or anything, so how do you know it's not working?

Comment: @MarkBaker Here the logic is normal, do not try to understand it, this is just a small portion of the method, a large class. I just edited my first post, added a few refinements.

Comment: Perhaps clarify what you're asking further then..... "does not work" doesn't describe your problem in any way, nor does "did not meet my expectations"..... did it generate an image that was incorrectly rotated? or reversed instead of rotated? or black and white instead of colour?

Comment: @MarkBaker Look this: http://pastebin.com/17bLsrRm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58934/discussion-between-romangorbatko-and-mark-baker).